# how can we know there is interactions between explanatory variables or quadratic when we write the generalized regression model?

Tags: regression, interaction

How can we know there are interactions between explanatory variables or quadratic when we write the  generalized regression model?

For example:

```
model.glm<-glm(skins ~ factor(block)*maturity*cure, family=poisson, weight=weight, data=model.df)
onions.glm<-glm(skins ~ factor(block)+maturity+cure+maturity:cure, family=poisson, weight=weight, data=onions.df),etc..
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you use different data frames (model.df and onions.df). In my answer, I'm going to assume that the data is identical in the two models.

In your two models, the difference is that in the second model you include all interactions between `factor(block)` and the other variables. The models are nested, which menas that the more simple model (model.glm) is a special case of the more complex model (onions.glm) if certain parameters are set to 0, namely the interactions between `factor(block)` and the other variables. This means that you can test the models using a likelihood-ratio test:

```
anova(model.glm, onions.glm, test="LR")
```

If the test is statistically significant, it means that the interactions contribute to the model in a meaningful way and that the more complex model (onions.glm) should be preferred. If the test is not significant, the simpler model should be preferred.